# Interpolar cadenas C#6

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Estoy interpolando cadenas y al final de la línea de código al poner el `;` me da un mensaje (*Empty statement is redundant*), pero igual compila el código, muestro imagen.

[image: Interpolar cadenas]

El código es el siguiente:

```
static void FillTheseValues(out int a, out string b, out bool c)
{
    a = 9;
    b = "Enjoy your string.";
    c = true;
}
Console.WriteLine("***** Fun with Methods *****");
int i;
string str;
bool b;
FillTheseValues(out i, out str, out b);
Console.WriteLine($"Int is: {i}");
Console.WriteLine($"String is: {str}");
```

Por cierto, estoy usando *Visual Studio 2015*, tengo instalado *ReSharper*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno , puede que sea el `ReSharper` que esté dando esos `warnings` inexplicables
trate de reiniciar esto

```
Herramientas -> Opciones 
-> ReSharper ->Suspender y Resume otra vez (sin necesidad de cerrar la ventana)  
(Si no funciona reinicie Visual Studio)
```

o tratar de darle formato así , (su equivalente )

```
/*Console.WriteLine($"Int is: {i}");*/
 Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Int is {0}", i));
/*Console.WriteLine($"String is: {str}");*/
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("String is {0}", str));
```

Comment: Hola, Dev Joel es justo lo que estoy haciendo, `Console.WriteLine("String is: {0}", str);`

Comment: Se soluciono ? El  `warning ` te lo provee el  `ReShaper`

Comment: Asi es @Dev Joel el problema es el ReSharper

Comment: Así es. ese fue el problema y podrá ser. más adelante quizá :)

Answer (score -1):

para evitar ese warning deberías inicializar la variable str por lo menos a cadena vacía.

```
string str = string.Empty;
```

Comment: Hola Sergio, hice lo que me recomiendas pero igual me da el mismo warning.

Comment: Sergio no hay problema cuando interpolo cadenas de esta manera `Console.WriteLine("String is: {0}", str);`

Comment: Sin usar el ReSharper, no me sale ese aviso.A ver si algún compañero que use esa tool puede darnos otra respuesta. Saludos

Comment: @SergioParra Esto parece ser cuestiones del  `ReShaper`  A veces da  `warnings` inexplicables.

Comment: @Dev.Joel. Por eso no me gusta ese tipo de herramientas.Con lo que viene de serie en VS me vale. Saludos

Comment: @SergioParra Que opinas del Productivity Power Tools 2015 o simplemente no usas ninguna Tool

Comment: No uso tools. Aunque tienen sus ventajas. Me he acostumbrado a mi forma de trabajar. Ojo, no digo que no funcionen bien o que no sean buenas herramientas, simplemente digo que a mi no me gustan. Es mi opinión